# Xtext 2.9 RuntimeModule

Tags: customization, xtext, xtend

I am trying to implement implicit import mechanism in my dsl (named ADSL). To do this I am following the approach applied to SmallJava example some 3 years ago, which is available here: [SmallJava source folder](https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-examples/tree/master/org.example.smalljava/src/org/example/smalljava). My dsl is very similar to SmallJava, so you might consider that I'm now trying to do essentially the same thing done in SmallJava.

I have defined a library (similar to the one of smalljava) and tried to implement the implicit import for it. To do this I need to customize ADSLRuntimeModule class, in a similar way to SmallJavaRuntimeModule.java.
However, I notice that in Xtext 2.9 in the source folder my ADSLRuntimeModule is xtend, not java file.

So, when I try to update my ADSLRuntimeModule.xtend I experience syntactic mistakes, as you can see in the screenshot [ADSLRuntimeModule.xtend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fubf5.png). It states that @Override is disallowed for this location.

Could someone please explain why I am facing this error and what is the correct way to do this customization?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to post your code. We don't know what you're doing.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, I updated the question with some more details. Hopefully it's more informative now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pasted Java code into an Xtend file. The equivalent Xtend syntax is this:

```
class ADSLRuntimeModule extends AbstractADSLRuntimeModule {

    override configureIScopeProviderDelegate(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(IScopeProvider)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named(AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.NAMED_DELEGATE))
            .to(ADSLImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Miro for correcting the syntax, it's compiling now. Probably needless to say, I'm a total beginner with xtend and xtext ;)